# How does Microsoft Translator Service handle double quotation marks?

Tags: microsoft-translator

I get all kinds of different results for using double quotation marks.
For example, they are translated to {" and "* for "Test error":

[image]

They are translated to [ and ] for "Test paper":
[image]

Could anyone shed some light on this?